# com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.NoSuchFolderException while adding multiple files fs repo?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I am getting the below error while i add multiple files to my liferay fs repository. Please advise. Thanks.

```
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.NoSuchFolderException: No DLFolder exists with the primary key 11375
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.persistence.DLFolderPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(DLFolderPersistenceImpl.java:9527)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.persistence.DLFolderPersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(DLFolderPersistenceImpl.java:9545)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryTypeLocalServiceImpl.getFileEntryTypesPrimaryFolderId(DLFileEntryTypeLocalServiceImpl.java:587)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryTypeLocalServiceImpl.getFolderFileEntryTypes(DLFileEntryTypeLocalServiceImpl.java:303)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryTypeServiceImpl.getFolderFileEntryTypes(DLFileEntryTypeServiceImpl.java:125)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryTypeServiceUtil.getFolderFileEntryTypes(DLFileEntryTypeServiceUtil.java:121) 14:15:00,003 INFO  [FastFactPublisher:21] Entering method receive(Message) with parameter :: message = {destinationName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, response=null, respo nseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=null, values={JOB_NAME=com.myNewFolder.net.portlet.test.scheduler.Publisher, EXCEPTIONS_MAX_SIZE=0, GROU P_NAME=com.dominos.intranet.portlet.fastfacts.scheduler.FastFactPublisher, DESTINATION_NAME=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, PORTLET_ID=admin_WAR_por tlet, JOB_STATE=com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.JobState@659804d0, companyId=0, MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME=com.myNewFolder.net.portlet.fastfacts.scheduler. tPublisher, RECEIVER_KEY=com.dominos.intranet.portlet.facts.scheduler.Publisher.com.myNewFolder.net.portlet.facts.scheduler.Publisher, MESSAGE_ LISTENER_UUID=0066aad0-0c4b-4770-81df-7fdb82f00785}} 14:15:00,017 INFO  [Publisher:32] Exiting method receive(Message) with return type void
```

Code Changes:

**\webapps\ROOT\html\portlet\document_library\add_button.jsp**

I had removed a condition `IsEmpty()` from the `if` statement to enable the option multiple document upload in `fsrepo`. Which definately enables the multiple document menu and i am able to drag the files in the section but as soon as i drag i get the error and the save section that needs to be present in the right hand corner is not seen.

```
<c:if test="<%= ((folder == null) || folder.isSupportsMultipleUpload()) && hasAddDocumentPermission  %>">
        <portlet:renderURL var="editFileEntryURL">
            <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/upload_multiple_file_entries" />
            <portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= currentURL %>" />
            <portlet:param name="backURL" value="<%= currentURL %>" />
            <portlet:param name="repositoryId" value="<%= String.valueOf(repositoryId) %>" />
            <portlet:param name="folderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" />
        </portlet:renderURL>

        <aui:nav-item href="<%= editFileEntryURL %>" label="multiple-documents" />
    </c:if>
```

Comment: Please provide some code snippet

Comment: @LuckyBoy : i am trying to make changes with the existing liferay code that is already present..to provide multiple file upload functionality in fs repo..I made the multiple file upload menu available but when i drag the files to upload i get the above exception.

Comment: did you check folder id getting passed correct ? Is FastFactPublisher & com.myNewFolder.net.portlet.test.scheduler.Publisher are your code ? Please share code in side these classes where you give call to API to add multiple files. It looks like folder ID passing to the API has some issue.

Comment: @Haris : Please check my updated question...Everything works perfect for me but i am trying to work on fsrepo part to enable multiple documents but i get the above exception.